# How to change your Minecraft character's name

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On my phone it changes the character's names weirdly. In order to change it, you have to press the delete button a bunch of times and press space to get rid of the name one letter at a time. I don't know how to put in a name because it always jumbles up the letters when I put it in.  And I have to delete it and start over again. I can't figure out how to make it type normally. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has something to do with your texting format.  Check your keyboard settings,  Maybe that is jumbled up.  It's possible  that your touch settings are on a different setting than the usual.  Hope this helps.